# Projecting a 2D point from a marker to the image with computed homography

Tags: opencv, homography, reprojection-error

I have a planar marker where I have run the **SIFT** algorithm to extract features. Then I run a detector to find this marker in the scene and extract features again. I match the points and extract the **homography** from the matched pairs with OpenCV using `findHomography()`.

Now I want to project the 2D points detected in the marker with the computed homography to compare the positions with the 3D points measured from the scene and calculate the **reprojection error**. I am confused with the pixel coordinates, centimeters, calibration matrices, I don't know which conversions should I do first.

Does anybody know a link on this or can explain the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call the homography matrix H, the camera matrix K (needed to convert to pixels) would be something like this, depending on your resolution.

```
Mat K= Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32FC1);
K.at<float>(0,0)=500.0f;        
K.at<float>(0,2)=320.0f;      // width/2    
K.at<float>(1,1)=500.0f;    
K.at<float>(1,2)=240.0f;      // height/2 
K.at<float>(2,2)=1.0f;
```

If your marker points are vector points of 2D:

```
vector<Point2f> marker_point; //containing coordinates in centimeters
```

then the projection would be like this, with the result a 3D point in pixel coordinates.

```
Mat point(3,1,CV_32FC1);        
point.at<float>(0) = marker_point.x;
point.at<float>(1) = marker_point.y;
point.at<float>(2) = 1.0f;
point = H* point;
point = point/point.at<float>(2);       //Normalize
point = K* point;                   //to pixels
```